# Why Google indexing blog.mywebsite.com instead of www.mywebsite.com?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, seo

All subdomains works in my website, example this:

```
mywebsite.com
www.mywebsite.com
blog.mywebsite.com
feed.mywebsite.com
anything.mywebsite.com
```

But Google indexed some of my website pages with blog.mywebsite.com, any idea why google indexed **blog** instead of **www**?

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? Why should Google not index blog.mywebsite.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you made it work. If you don't want it to work, either make it not work or make it redirect to the name you want. If they're all equally good, which you get it arbitrary.

Comment: But it's wierd! I'm not displaying any page as blog.mywebsite.com!